# Custom Object properties - multiple primitive variables or array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, variables, object, primitive

I'm rather fresh in programming and I try to make simple app. App will allow user to make a character sheet for popular RPG game. Right now I trying to model it (on paper) and have (maybe a stupid one) question.

Each character have set of skills - a lot (33). And each skill cane have value of 0-5. Now my question is: is it better to make 33 ints insied Character object or make Class Skill and make array of Skills in Character? My knowledge of Java is not good enough to decide :( If anyone find some useful article about it or can just simply explain it to me I would be grateful.

I just hope it is not completely stupid question :)
Have a nice day!

Comment: Don't call your class `Character` (that's taken). You could have an enum called `Skill` and then you could store the values in an `EnumMap<Skill, Integer>`. This is like using an array, except you can get the values from meaningful names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of skills you can use multiple attributes, will increase readability when used, but will make your class a bit ugly and less mantainable.

If values are always an `int`, I would reccomend to use a `Map` instead of `array` or `Collection`.

```
Map<String, Integer> skills;
```

So you can have a class with nice declaration and refer to skills by name and not by position in the array:

```
Integer strenghtLevel = skills.get("strenght");
```

Comment: Indeed I have fixed number of skills and I know I will not change them. Thank you for answer.

Comment: also if you change number of skills, `Map` will fil your requirements, it's a really beautiful solution I use a lot

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend to create a specific Skill class. Today you are using ints from 0 to 5; but such things tend to become more complex pretty fast.

Therefore you should carefully design the "Skill" class upfront (you might also consider to have a Skill interface; as you might face the need to have different implementations (for different skill types) at some future point).

You character class could then be using a dynamic container; for example java.util.ArrayList to hold all the various skills.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to make a class skill, because then you can ensure each skill has a name and a value. Then, you can also do things like creating a method to print out or display the name and value, and if you want to add another attribute to the skill, it is fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of int elements. It should be enough, unless you want some custom logic. If the values should have states and actions, then they should be objects.